# Why does git Submodule show wrong branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

We have a superproject and a submodule contained within it. Both have the same branches `master, staging, featureBranch`.

I would like the superproject on `master` to track the submodule on `master` and the superproject on `staging` to track the submodule on `staging`.

for master in the superproject the `.gitmodules` looks like this:

```
[submodule "submodule"]
        path = submodule
        url = http://fpr-dev/submodule.git
        branch = master
```

and on staging

```
[submodule "submodule"]
        path = submodule
        url = http://fpr-dev/submodule.git
        branch = staging
```

now when I am on master an do a `git submodule` I see the following output:

```
$ git submodule
+e3782f37b1ae23aa0d5537ef3061dfdfec70f77f submodule (heads/Staging)
```

Please note it says staging. But when I do a git status inside the submodule I see:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

**Why is this so and how can I fix it?**

now when I switch to `staging` and try to pull (`git.exe pull -v --progress  "origin"`) the submodule I get the following error:

```
You asked to pull from the remote 'origin', but did not specify
a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote
for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.
```

**All I want to do is:**

- Superproject and submodule should have the same branches (Staging, feature, ...).
- when switching the superproject to a different branch I want the submodule to follow the superprojects branch (i.e. also switch to that branch) I don't care if this is done automaticalle or I have to run a 1000 lines script
- When doing a push or pull in the submodule it should just work (i.e. push/pull the correct branch)

What is the easiest way to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

When you run `git submodule` it shows the correct commit SHA for your submodule, because this is what you have set in your super project. That command doesn't tell you what commit SHA your current local submodule code references; it tells you want the super project **wants** to reference.

Unfortunately you have to go an extra step to tell your super project to pull down that specific submodule code locally. This is done by running these commands:

`git submodule init`

`git submodule update`

After this you should see the correct code in your submodule locally.  The only time you could bypass these extra commands is when you clone the repo for the first time.  You can call this:

`git clone <repo_name> --recursive`

and all submodules will be checked out at the correct commit SHA.  However, as soon as you checkout a new branch, you will have to run the `init` and `update` commands again.

To automate this behavior you could create a script that you would run instead of using the `git checkout` command directly. The script could accept a branch name, and would look something like this:

`git checkout <branch_name>`

`git submodule init`

`git submodule update`

Comment: I did this: (cd mysubmodule && git checkout mybranch && git submodule init && git submodule update), afterwards the child reports the correct branch, but the parent still says the submodule is on the old branch.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you ever got this working, but we use a solution that involves Git hooks, specifically the post-checkout hook.  This will make it so when you switch branches in a superproject, it will attempt to checkout that same-named branch in the submodule; If the branch doesn't exist in the submodule, it will attempt to checkout 'develop' (in your case, you probably want a different branch name, like 'staging').
NOTE:  Regardless of the branch checked out, the superproject will still make sure that the submodule is on the correct commit $SHA after the branch checkout.

E.G. If the superproject expects submoduleA at commit_hash=848f7b when the superproject is on `staging`, that will happen regardless of whether submoduleA is tracking a branch or not.

In your .git/hooks folder of your superproject, add a file called `post-checkout` and put the following code into it.

```
#!/bin/bash

# NOTE: This hook runs before the --recursive part of
# the checkout.  This means that the submodules have not
# yet been updated to their required commit.

PREV_COMMIT=$1;
POST_COMMIT=$2;
CURRENT_DIRECTORY=$(pwd);

# If we update the parent repo to a named branch that
# should also exist in the child repos, checkout that
# branch in the child repos
# [parent checks out Develop, children should also check
# out develop... not just move HEAD ref]
#
if git branch | grep -Eqx '^\* [^ ]*$'; #if we just checked out a named branch(not a HEAD checkout)
then
    BRANCH_NAME=$(git branch | sed -E 's/^\* ([^ ]*)$/\1/;t;d');
    # if the branch exists in a submodule, check out that branch.
    #If the branch doesn't exist, but the hash of the commit to
    # checkout is the same as develop, then checkout develop instead of the hash

    git submodule foreach "
    develop_sha=\$(git rev-parse develop);
    if git branch | grep -Eq '$BRANCH_NAME'; then
        git checkout '$BRANCH_NAME';
    elif [ \"\$sha1\" = \"\$develop_sha\" ]; then
        git checkout develop;
    fi || :";
fi
```